# Java - Get all local field values of an object as map

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, gson, tostring

I want to retrieve a map of **field-values** present in a **java object**. I tried *`com.google.Gson`* and *`org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder`* to retrieve all the details regarding the given object. But following problems occured :

1. **com.google.Gson**:

   ```
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder.create();
   String str = gson.reflectionToString(myObject);
   ```

   StackOverFlowError occurs for some objects, even a map having JSONObject fails miserably.
2. **org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder**:

   ```
   String str = ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(myObject);
   ```

   While using the above API for HashMap, variables inside the HashMap are displayed but contents of the HashMap are not visible.

   Output :

   > samplePackage.CustomHashMap@5fec459b[accessOrder=false,threshold=12,loadFactor=0.75]

Help me to find the perfect solution !

Comment: You could loop over all the non static  fields of the class. About 4-6 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using reflection. This allows you to use your class name to access your class and its meta data. You can then use the getDeclaredFields method to get all the declared Fields for your class. Your fields can be private this way so they can't be edited by outside classes without calling getters or setters.

```
//initialize the name of your class.
String className = "examplePackageName.exampleClassName";
//get your class using the name of the class
Class<? extends ObjectImplementation> Classtouse = Class.forName(className);
//initialize map of fieldnames to field objects from reflection
Map<String,Field> FieldMap = new HashMap<>();
//gets delcared fields as a List, converts it to an array and for each element in the 
//array, it maps the element's name to the element itself as a field object
Arrays.asList(Classtouse.getDeclaredFields()).forEach(Field -> FieldMap.put(Field.getName(),Field));
//now you have your fieldmap ready to use.
```

when you want to access the value of a Field, you can use

```
//instantiate an object of your Class with type Classtouse here
//use the object created in the line above and set its fields using the line 
//below
field.get(//Object that holds this field);
```

Where field is the Field object you want to edit which you accessed using the fieldname or some other method. If you want to map fieldnames to field values directly you can edit this from the code above:

```
Arrays.asList(Classtouse.getDeclaredFields()).forEach(Field -> FieldMap.put(Field.getName(),Field));
```

to be:

```
Arrays.asList(Classtouse.getDeclaredFields()).forEach(Field -> FieldMap.put(Field.getName(),Field.get(//your object here)));
```

Just make sure you have instantiated an object you want to do this with first.
An example of this and other reflection methods can be found in the Field javadoc
Here:[link]https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html

This code is not garenteed to be perfectly runnable but it's close.

Comment: You have explained about getting the field names in a class. But I need values of those fields inside a constructed object.

Comment: Updated my answer to fit your needs. Hope this helps!